# Removing items from a list on Flutter

Tags: list, flutter

i'm having a problem removing items from a list.
I want to remove the tapped item, but when i put the removing command i got a error:
"I/flutter ( 9410): Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type '() => void'"

````
             child: ListView.builder(
                 // padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                 itemCount: _pecasList.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                   return ListTile(
                       key: Key(
                           DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()),
                       title: Text(_pecasList[index]["title"]),
                       onTap: _pecasList.removeAt(index)); //<<Trying to remove
                 }),
           ), ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
onTap: _pecasList.removeAt(index)
```

With:

```
onTap: ()=>_pecasList.removeAt(index)
```